# How can I increase height of view(xib file) and add more UI elements to the scrollview?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

As I show in picture I want to add label and some other UI element to the scrollview which is in View but there is no more space left at the bottom.The height of view is not editable:

[image]

So what should I do? I can not work with xib file! Should I place them programmatically or there are some clever ways?

Comment: Go to attributes inspector and change size (first one) to Freeform and now you can change height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your root view (top most view of your xib)!

Then select `attribute inspector` -> change size to `FreeForm` from `Inferred`(default)

then from `size inspector` you can change height of your view.

Please check below screenshots for better understanding !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size to freeform in attribute inspector.

Refer the below image:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Changed Simulated Size to Freeform.